Data Driven Testing - Unable to read values from Excel Selenium
I am trying to read the values from Excel using selenium java through eclipse. Imported the apache poi jar files successfully.
public class DDT {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws EncryptedDocumentException, IOException {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("E:\\DDT\\DDT.xlsx");
        Workbook wb = WorkbookFactory.create(fis);
        String str = wb.getSheet("Sheet1").getRow(1).getCell(1).getStringCellValue();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}

Trying to find a solution mostly suggested to make change in pom.xml file. But in my porject i don't have an pox.xml file. how to solve this?

Output error:


pom.xml is used for a maven project. It is not a required precondition for a java project.
You can add the required 3rd party library the referenced libraries of Eclipse.
You can try the solution in How to add a reference in Eclipse. add the required apache poi library to your project before run it.
If the POI library is already added to the project. Please expand the library to confirm the required class file(org.apache.commons.io.output.UnsynchronizedByteArrayOutputStream.class) exists in jar file.
the screenshot is for your reference.

Update:
Download Apache Commons IO from: https://commons.apache.org/io/download_io.cgi
Download the Binaries zip file then unzip the file. Add the unzipped jar file to your reference libraries.
Maybe you need to try different versions if the latest version incompatible with the POI version used in your project.

i have already added the poi library jar files to my project but still getting this failure

Hi, please confirm the class file exists in the referenced library. I add a screenshot for  your reference.

No those class file is not available. May i know how to solve this?

I find this class file is in "commons-io" library. Please download "Apache Commons IO" library and add it to your reference libraries.

How to download that and add that in my project. In my project i dont see none of the .class file generated under referenced library.

The answer updated for how to add "Apache Commons IO" library.

After adding the "Apache Commons IO" library still facing error. But i referred another website for the solution https://atechlearn.blogspot.com/2018/09/how-to-resolve-exception-in-thread-main.html  by additional "commons-compress-1.27.1-bin" to the project it resolves the issue.
